# ANSI SQL - wildcard alias?

Tags: sql

If I have a table like this:

```
a: string
b: string
c: string
```

I'd like to be able to perform transformations on certain columns but also pass each column through verbatim. So like this:

```
a_transform, b_transform, c_transform, a_raw, b_raw, c_raw
```

Is it possible to do that with a wildcard, something like this:

```
select
fn(a) as a_transform,
fn(b) as b_transform,
fn(c) as c_transform,
* as *_raw
```

or do I have to enumerate each column individually?

Comment: Just a note: according to **ANSI SQL**, a single `*` must be alone in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the wildcard retrieving the columns with their original names.

```
SELECT
fn(a) AS a_transform,
fn(b) AS b_transform,
fn(c) AS c_transform,
*
```

will result in:

```
a_transform, b_transform, c_transform, a, b, c
```